# Is it possible to check the code of a function in R of a package's previous version?

Tags: r, package

A professor shared his R code, where he start by redefining an existing function `f` from `package X.X.1`. The package has been updated since then, so that now I have `package X.X.3` installed. 
His modified code and the function code in version `X.X.3` are almost the same, aside from little things which don't really impact its purpose.

I wonder whether it's possible to look for its code in older versions (aka `X.X.1`) of the package (to see what has changed) WITHOUT having to download the older versions (I've seen from other SO questions that it is possible to download the older versions of the package, but I'd prefer just looking at the older codes, if possible), and so to avoid rewriting the version I have now.

Comment: If the prof maintains (or maintained) it on some form of web-available version control (e.g., [github](https://github.com/), [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/), [r-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/)), then "yes", conditioned on the availability of that tool. Otherwise, likely not.

Comment: Overwriting the version you have now shouldn't be that big a deal. Just install the old version, check out the code you want to, then install the new version again. Shouldn't take more than 2 minutes or so... Otherwise you'll need version control.